# Ajax request in Rails/JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

there is some JQuery code which makes Ajax request:

```
$.getJSON(ruby_url, function(data) {
    //some code
});
```

And there is the following Ruby code:

```
def some_method
  #save get json from other web-service and save it to json
  render json:@json
end
```

It works good. But the first line of my method just makes HTTP request to other server to get JSON response from it. Because other service just returns clean JSON I've changed ruby_url to other_service_url; now my JQuery script doesn't work, $.getJSON function receives no data. What is the cause of it? How can I fix it? I'm trying to change $.getJSON to $.get, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Is there an error in your JavaScript console?  When you debug this in the browser, what actually happens and in what way does it fail?  Is the request sent?  What response is received?  Maybe `other_service_url` is a cross-domain request and not permitted by AJAX?

Comment: No errors, no response body(response code is 200), request is sented

Comment: If the ajax is cross-domain, you may need to use jsonp